# Replace token's text in ANTLR

Tags: c#, antlr, lexer

I'm trying to replace some token's text from my input program to a specific formated text. I'm using C# as output language.

Example of input:

```
time#1m2s
```

My lex grammar for that input:

```
fragment
DIGIT : '0'..'9'
      ;

CTE_DURATION 
    : ('T'|'t'|'TIME'|'time') '#' '-'? (DIGIT ('d'|'h'|'m'|'s'|'ms') '_'?)+
    ;
```

Output token text I'd like to get from input example:

```
0.0:1:2.0
```

That's means: 0 days, 0 hours, 1 minute, 2 seconds and 0 milliseconds.

Any advice? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I dont understand your question, can u be more specific? Is your question that you want your grammar to accept input in this format only: 0.0:1:2.0?

Comment: My lex grammar accepts "time#1m2s" and creates a CTE_DURATION token which text is "time#1m2s". I want my lex rule to change CTE_DURATION token text (in my example, i want to change token text to "0.0:1:2.0").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do that (it's in Java, but shouldn't be hard  to port to C#):

```
grammar Test;

parse
 : CTE_DURATION EOF
 ;

CTE_DURATION 
 : ('T' 'IME'? | 't' 'ime'?) '#' minus='-'?
   (d=DIGITS 'd')? (h=DIGITS 'h')? (m=DIGITS 'm')? (s=DIGITS 's')? (ms=DIGITS 'ms')?
   {
     int days = $d == null ? 0 : Integer.valueOf($d.text);
     int hours = $h == null ? 0 : Integer.valueOf($h.text);
     int minutes = $m == null ? 0 : Integer.valueOf($m.text);
     int seconds = $s == null ? 0 : Integer.valueOf($s.text);
     int mseconds = $ms == null ? 0 : Integer.valueOf($ms.text);
     setText(($minus == null ? "" : "-") + days + "." + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + mseconds);
   }
 ;

fragment DIGITS : '0'..'9'+;
```

Parsing the input `time#1m2s` results in the following parse tree:

[image]

Note that the grammar now accepts `time#` as well (causing it to produce `0.0:0:0.0`), but you can easily produce an exception from the lexer rule in case such input is invalid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That solves my problem. I had to use "$text" instead of "setText()" in target C#. How can I add minus symbol ('-') to my output (minus is optional)?

Comment: I tried that way before writing my comment. That always produces an ouput with '-'. EDIT: I've got the solution for the optional minus adding a new lex rule: "fragment MINUS  : '-' ;". I used MINUS inside CTE_DURATION rule. Thank you.